# How to set-mailboxfolderpermission with import-csv

Tags: powershell, exchange

I want to import bulk zoom from CSV file.

```
The csv file format: name,email,capacity
```

And I create the room with the script as below:

```
$roomlist = import-csv roomlist.csv

foreach($room in $roomlist){
New-Mailbox -Alias $room.email -Database MBX01 -Name $room.name -OrganizationalUnit “Domain/Users” -ResourceCapacity $room.capacity -room
Set-mailboxfolderpermission -identity "${room.name}:\Calendar" -AccessRights Reviewer -User Default
}
```

The zoom creating was success, but fail on Set-mailboxfolderpermission.
How could I fix it?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOoGq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify this row from:

```
Set-mailboxfolderpermission -identity "${room.name}:\Calendar" -AccessRights Reviewer -User Default
```

to:

```
Set-mailboxfolderpermission -identity "$($room.name):\Calendar" -AccessRights Reviewer -User default
```

And see if it helps.

Comment: It's work! Thanks for your big help.

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept it as the answer if it helps with this question.